# How correctly to set property from one function of the designer in another?

Tags: javascript

I want to set in `weapon` property  `bow` to the archer. But when you call the `toString` method, an error is displayed:

> this.weapon._getDamage is not a function

```
function Weapon(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
        value: function () {
            return name + ' damage: ' + damage + " points";
        }
    });
}
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);
console.log(bow.toString()); // Golden bow,  damage: 20 points
function Unit(basicDamage, type) {
    this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this._type = type;
    this._setWeapon = function (weapon) {
        var me = this;
        me.weapon = weapon;
        return me;
    };
    this._getDamage = function () {
        return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0) + this._basicDamage;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type-" + this._type + ",Have weapon -" + this.weapon +
"," +  ', hero current damage-' + this._getDamage() + 'points';
    }
}
function Archer(basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this._type = "archer";

}
var archer = new Archer(50);
archer._setWeapon(bow);
console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: `this.weapon._getDamage()` - but there is no `_getDamage()` in your `Weapon` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to number

```
   return +this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0 + this._basicDamage;
```

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'toString', {
        value: function () {
            return name + ' damage: ' + damage + " points";
        }
    });
}
var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow, ', 20);

function Unit(basicDamage, type) {
    this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this._type = type;
    this._setWeapon = function (weapon) {
        var me = this;
        me.weapon = weapon;
        return me;
    };
    this._getDamage = function () {
        return +this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0 + this._basicDamage;
    };
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type-" + this._type + ",Have weapon -" + this.weapon +"," +  ', hero current damage-' + this._getDamage() + 'points';
    }
}
function Archer(basicDamage) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this._type = "archer";

}
var archer = new Archer(50);
archer._setWeapon(bow);
console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: but still the property "this.weapon" is undefined

Comment: this should be the expected result .  

`Type-archer, Have weapon -Golden bow,  damage: 20 points, hero current damage-50 points`

Comment: `this.weapon` is an `object`. Why convert it to a number?

Answer (score 1):

Weapons have a `damage` property, not a `getDamage()`. `getDamage()` is the method you are establishing.

Also, you forgot `this` in your `Weapon.toString()` when getting the `name` and `damage` properties.

Your `setWeapon` property doesn't need to return `me` (or anything for that matter). All you need to do is set the property value.

Next, I don't see the point of the `Archer` constructor function. Since `Unit` expects a `type` argument anyway, just make a `new Unit()`.

Lastly, methods should be added to the constructor function's `prototype`, not the constructor function itself. This allows the method to be defined and stored just once, not on every instance. Along with this, you don't really need `Object.defineProperty()` in your case because you can just create a new property on the `prototype`.

```js
function Weapon(name, damage) {
    this.name = name;
    this.damage = damage;
}

// Methods should be added to the prototype, not the constructor function
Weapon.prototype.toString =  function () {
  return this.name + ' damage: ' + this.damage + " points";
};

function Unit(basicDamage, type) {
  this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
  this._type = type;
}

Unit.prototype._setWeapon = function (weapon) {
  this.weapon = weapon;
};

Unit.prototype._getDamage = function () {
  // Weapons have "damage", not "getDamage()"
  return (this.weapon ? this.weapon.damage : 0) + this._basicDamage;
};

Unit.prototype.toString = function () {
  return "Type-" + this._type + ", Have weapon -" + this.weapon +
         "," +  ', hero current damage-' + this._getDamage() + 'points';
};

var bow = new Weapon('Golden bow,', 20);
console.log(bow.toString()); // Golden bow,  damage: 20 points
var archer = new Unit(50, "Archer");
archer._setWeapon(bow);
console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: my task is to use only functional inheritance